# Laravel 5.* multiple middleware whole controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

How can i define multiple middlewares for all routes in particular controller?
Yes, i can define one midd in __constructor like:

```
$this->middleware( 'somemidd' );
```

and yes, i can define multiple midds for route like:

```
Route::get('/', ['middleware' => ['MyMiddleware', 'MySecondMiddleware'], function () {
    //
}]);
```

define multiple midds for Route::resourse is not solution, coz i have custom methods in my controller.
And i dont want to put midd in global scope Kernel\ protected $middleware = ...

How can i solve this?

Comment: What what are your reasons for avoiding `$this->middleware()` in the constructor?

Comment: I want something like $this->middleware( ['firstmid', 'secondmid'] );

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use **Middleware Groups**:

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],
];
```

Also you can use many middlewares in `__construct()` method:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new UserController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');

        $this->middleware('log', ['only' => [
            'fooAction',
            'barAction',
        ]]);

        $this->middleware('subscribed', ['except' => [
            'fooAction',
            'barAction',
        ]]);
    }
}
```

More: [HTTP Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers), [HTTP Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware).

Comment: On this example, does this means that the `auth` middleware will be applied for everything, and the other two middlewares would be applied with their constraints?

Comment: @OmarTarek that's right. Everything in this controller (second example).

Comment: Ok quick question, what If I don't have a second middleware but instead I have a guard, so I have 'auth' and 'auth:admin' for example, can I define them in the same way?